# Bind right click contect menu to key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, menu

I'm using a Latitude DELL notebook with XUbuntu which is working really well.
But there's this one issue. The missing "context menu" key which is usually between CTRL and AltGR.

I already found a way to press the "right key" but it only opens the context menu at my coursors point and not for example the focused text in firefox.

Is there some way to open the context menu for the selected item?
(Like the menu key on every normal keyboard would do)

Cheers.

Comment: Not familiar with `xfce` but on `gnome` `SHIFT+F10` opens the context menu.

Comment: Wow, that did it. I can't believe how I never found that. Thank you so much.